# Replace List Item Appinventor

Tags: app-inventor

I have a TinyDB and in each tag of the TinyDB I have a list.
Each list has 3 items, each indexed as 1, 2 and 3.
I want to change the 3rd item, index 3.
So I have done the following

[image]

So I want to now save the change in the TinyDB
and have added a storeValue command as follows.

[image]

I figured out how to get the valuetoStore variable. As follows.

[image]

I had done this before, and thought it wrong because it still doesn't change the 3rd item in the list. But I've added a notifier to look at it and it's correct. So the "replace list item" isn't working how I thought it should. It isn't replacing the 3rd item with an "n."

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second try is almost correct. The only thing is, you should use the `replace list item` block together with the local variable `name` instead of retrieving the value again from `TinyDB`.

**So what is the difference to your "solution"?**
 Currently you assign the list to a local variable `name`. Then you use the `replace list item` block together with a list, you can't store somewhere (you are loading the list again from `TinyDB`). And in the end you store variable `name` (which doesn't have been modified at all) in `TinyDB`. Therefore the solution is to use the `replace list item` block together with the local variable `name` instead of retrieving the value again from `TinyDB`. Btw. a better name for the local variable `name` would be `list`.

**Further tips**
Also in the definition of the local variable `name` you should add a block, e.g. an `empty string` or `0`

And if you want simplify a little bit, you can move the definition of the local variable `name` inside the `for each` loop. And alternatively of using the `for each number` loop, for list it's easier to use the `for each item in list` loop, see also the [documentation](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/support/blocks/control.html#foreach). The list in your case is `TinyDB1.GetTags`.

[image]

As already said in the [forum](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/a_VV4hmVpoE/-Xc27GIbnYQJ), generally I would use a list of lists and store it in only one tag in TinyDB
[How to work with Lists](http://www.imagnity.com/tutorials/app-inventor/list-blocks-on-app-inventor/) by Saj
[How to work with Lists and Lists of lists](http://www.appinventor.org/bookChapters/chapter19.pdf) (pdf) by [appinventor.org](http://www.appinventor.org/)

Comment: You are a genius 大風 and correct.
Obviously there is a different between the two, but what is the difference? the should equal each other.

Comment: I see. Thanks again. This sure is one very flexible language.